# MultipleChoiceField in Django not working

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to use a forms.MultipleChoiceField in Django, and form.is_valid returns True, but the query in my views.py returns "matching query does not exist."

forms.py:

```
LIST_INTERESTS = (
    ('Energy', 'Energy'),
    ('Business', 'Business'),
    ('Social', 'Social'),
    ('Mobile', 'Mobile'),
)
interests = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=LIST_INTERESTS, initial='Energy')
```

views.py:

```
temp_interests = list(form.cleaned_data['interests']),
for i in temp_interests:
    b = Interests.objects.get(val=i)
```

...at which point it will complain that something matching the query does not exist. Any ideas?

**Bonus info:**

When I plugged temp_interests into debug.html:

```
{% for i in temp_interests %}
    {{ i }}<br>
{% endfor %}
```

it returns [u'Answer 1', u'Answer 2']

Comment: show us the `Interests` model

Comment: if you don't have a model. Just use "form.as_p" to display the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in this line:

```
b = Interests.objects.get(val=i)
```

in the [`get()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get) method.

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. but what `get()` method does is returns a single matching query using the arguments passed. If it is not able to find any object using the arguments passed it raises the `DoesNotExist` exception, and that is what is happening in your case.

[NOTE: Also, make sure you use the `get()` when you are sure that there is only one object that exists according to the arguments passed. If you are not sure you can use the [`filter()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-specific-objects-with-filters) method which returns a list of all the objects that matches the given query.]

You need to make sure that an `Interest` object exists where `val` attribute is equal to the value you are passing. So in the above case, there is no `Interest` object where `val` is equal to `i`'s value and hence the Exception is raised.

To debug the above you can add a print statement as follows:

```
temp_interests = list(form.cleaned_data['interests']),
for i in temp_interests:
    print i  # Debug
    b = Interests.objects.get(val=i)
```

and check the server to see which `value` the exception is being raised on.

Answer (score 0):

If `Interests` is a model, you can try this using a ModelMulitpleChoiceField instead:

```
interests = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Interests.objects.all())
```

This way the the `interests` field gets populated with the actual objects from the `Interests` models instead of a list